# Issues with conditionals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
          CODE      DATE    MONTH_DAY  PPTOT   SECTOR_1
0       472606FA 2001-01-01   01-01    0.0         SN
1       472606FA 2001-01-02   01-02    0.0         SN
2       472606FA 2001-01-03   01-03    0.7         SN
3       472606FA 2001-01-04   01-04    NaN         SN
4       472606FA 2001-01-05   01-05    NaN         SN
         ...        ...     ...    ...        ...
248220  47E2A75C 2021-04-26   04-26    0.0         SI
248221  47E2A75C 2021-04-27   04-27    0.0         SI
248222  47E2A75C 2021-04-28   04-28    0.0         SI
248223  47E2A75C 2021-04-29   04-29    0.0         SI
248224  47E2A75C 2021-04-30   04-30    NaN         SI

[248225 rows x 5 columns]
```

I want to apply 2 conditionals. When `df['PPTOT'] <= 0` and `df['SECTOR_1']=='CS'`, `df['PPTOT']`
must be `np.nan`. So i did this code:

```
df.loc[(df['PPTOT'] <= 0 & df['SECTOR_1']=='CS'), 'PPTOT'] = np.nan
```

But i get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'
```

So i wrote the parenthesis only in `df['PPTOT'] <= 0` like this:

```
df.loc[(df['PPTOT'] <= 0) & df['SECTOR_1']=='CS', 'PPTOT'] = np.nan
```

But i get again another error:

```
ValueError: unknown type str64
```

How can i solve this? or maybe there is another efficient or accurate way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! you tried add parenthesis in both conditions, somethis like:  

`df.loc[(df['PPTOT'] <= 0) & (df['SECTOR_1']=='CS'), 'PPTOT'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` operator has higher precedence than `<=`, `==`, etc., so you have to add parentheses around the second condition as well.

```
df.loc[(df['PPTOT'] <= 0) & (df['SECTOR_1']=='CS'), 'PPTOT'] = np.nan
```